# Can the FAA CPL 2-hour cross country flight requirement include stops?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, logging, cpl

One of the [requirements](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?pitd=20180727&node=se14.1.61_1129&rgn=div8) for an FAA commercial certificate is:

> §61.129: (3) 20 hours of training on the areas of operation listed in §61.127(b)(1) of this part that includes at least—
>
> ...
>
> (iii) One 2-hour cross country flight in a single engine airplane in daytime conditions that consists of a total straight-line distance of more than 100 nautical miles from the original point of departure;

Since it just says 100 nautical miles from the original point of departure, would a flight that was 268 NM and 2h 29m, but included a stop halfway count for this requirement?

Also, does the "20 hours of training" mean that the 2-hour/100 NM flight needs to be with an instructor?

Comment: is it just me or is "nm" nanometers while "NM" is nautical miles?

Comment: @FreeMan updated, but I think it was pretty clear in context.

Comment: Sorry, that was really just me thinking out loud as a non-pilot and being momentarily confused by your title.

Comment: The general rule of reading the FARs is “Don’t make them more complicated than they are.” If you are in the air more than 2 hours and land at a point more than 100 nm away, then you have satisfied the requirement. I used my flight to get night current and landed at 2 airports along the way.

Comment: @JScarry - Another way to state your point: who's to say the halfway stop isn't *the* destination, and the second leg is just another flight?

Comment: @ymb1 In his case, yes. In my case, the destination was 131 nm away and in a  C210 is less than an hour. So the round-trip time would be less than 2 hours. Adding the stops along the way extended the total flying time to more than 2 hours.

Comment: Everything in §61.129 Part 3 falls under the training wording so an instructor is required. They should explicitly log it as training required by §61.129 in your log book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Affirmative.  That flight will have to be part of the dual training time required for the airman certificate.

And, yes, you can do a stopover during the flight; the experience requirement does not prohibit it.